# Camel maximumRedeliveries is ignored

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I try to use Camel to deliver files from one folder to a rest call and Im trying to achieve that on Error it's tried to redeliver twice and then moved to an error folder if the second redelivery fails as well. My code in the RouteBuilder's configure method looks like this:

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("file:///home/camelerror").useOriginalMessage());

        from("file:///home/camelefiles")
                .onException(RetryableException.class)
                .log("RetryableException handled")
                .maximumRedeliveries(2)
                .end()
                .routeId(port.id())
                .throwException(new RetryableException());
```

I get the "RetryableException handled" logs so I guess the exception is handled correctly but it redelivers the message an infinite number of times.
What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve that the message is only redelivered twice and then the deadLetterChannel is used?

Comment: AFAIR the `.log` instruction in your current form should be performed only once per `onException` invocation. If you want to log per redelivery attempt use `.onRedelivery((Exchange exchange) -> LOG.debug("..."))`. With that being said, I think as you don't move/delete the file after consumption your file consumer is reading the same file(s) in every time and thus give the impression that the `onException` block is attempting redeliveries all the time. Try to append something like `?moveFailed=.error` to your consumer definition to move a failed file to an `.error` subdirectory

Comment: I suggest you to test the error processing with a more simple from endpoint, for instance `from("timer://test?delay=10s&repeatCount=1")` which will fire your route only once after 10 sec. This way you will be able to check the exact number of log is printed